# Faster way to search strings in big file with python

Tags: python, nlp

I have two text files to be processed. Here is my situation:

- These two files are extremely big, one is 1.21 GB and another is 1.1 GB. Each of them contain about over 30 million lines of Chinese strings.
- Each string in each file is unique.
- I don't have to modify these files, once they're loaded, they will not change.

The thing is, one of these file is corrupted. Let's call it N5. N5 should have each line of string looks like this: 'a5 b5 c5 d5 e5\tf5'

Instead, it is: 'a5b5 c5 d5 e5\tf5'

I am trying to recovery it from another file, let's call it N4, it looks like this: 'a4 b4 c4 d4\tf4'

What I am trying to do is using N4 to separate a5b5 in N5, which might have three results:

1. 'a4 b4 c4 d4' equals 'a5 b5 c5 d5'
2. 'a4 b4 c4 d4' equals 'b5 c5 d5 e5'
3. There is no match for N4 in N5.

In situation 1 and 2, I can get the answer. However, in 3, it takes about 140 seconds to complete the search in N4.

I am now using list to store N4 and N5, and down below is my code for comparing them.

```
# test data
N4 = ['a1 b1 c1 e1\t3', 'a2 b2 c2 e2\t2', 'c3 e3 f3 g3\t3']
N5 = ['a1b1 c1 e1 f1\t2', 'a2b c2 e2 f2\t1', 'b3c3 e3 f3 g3\t3']

# result stroage
list_result = []
list_result_no_none = []

counter_none = 0

list_len = len(N4)

for each_item in N5:
    counter_list_len = 0
    list_str_2 = str(each_item).split(' ')
    list_str_2_2 = str(list_str_2[3]).split('\t')
    str_list_str_2_0 = str(list_str_2[0])
    for each_item in N4:
        list_str_1 = str(each_item).split(' ')
        list_str_1_2 = str(list_str_1[3]).split('\t')

        # if n4 y == n5
        if (str(list_str_1[0])+str(list_str_1[1]) == str(list_str_2[0]) and \
           (str(list_str_1[2]) == str(list_str_2[1]) and \
           (str(list_str_1_2[0]) == str(list_str_2[2])) and \
           (str(list_str_1_2[1]) >= str(list_str_2_2[1])))) :

            list_result.append(list_str_1[0] +' '+ list_str_1[1] +' '+ list_str_1[2] +' '+ list_str_1_2[0] +' '+ list_str_2[3])
            list_result_no_none.append(list_str_1[0] +' '+ list_str_1[1] +' '+ list_str_1[2] +' '+ list_str_1_2[0] +' '+ list_str_2[3])
        break

        # if x n4 == n5
        elif ((str(list_str_1[0]) in (str(list_str_2[0]))) and \
            (str(list_str_1[1]) == str(list_str_2[1])) and \
            (str(list_str_1[2]) == str(list_str_2[2])) and \
            (str(list_str_1_2[0]) == str(list_str_2_2[0]) and \
            (str(list_str_1_2[1]) >= str(list_str_2_2[1])))):

            list_result.append(str_list_str_2_0[0:(str(list_str_2[0]).find(str(list_str_1[0])))]\
            +' '+ str_list_str_2_0[(str(list_str_2[0]).find(str(list_str_1[0]))):len(list_str_2[0])]\
            +' '+ list_str_1[1] +' '+ list_str_1[2] +' '+ list_str_2[3])
        list_result_no_none.append(str_list_str_2_0[0:(str(list_str_2[0]).find(str(list_str_1[0])))]\
            +' '+ str_list_str_2_0[(str(list_str_2[0]).find(str(list_str_1[0]))):len(list_str_2[0])]\
            +' '+ list_str_1[1] +' '+ list_str_1[2] +' '+ list_str_2[3])
        break

        # not found
        else:
            counter_list_len += 1
            if counter_list_len == list_len:
                list_result.append('none' +' '+ list_str_2[0] +' '+ list_str_2[1] +' '+ list_str_2[2] +' '+ list_str_2[3])
                counter_none += 1


print(list_result)
print(list_result_no_none)
print("Percentage of not found: %.2f" % ((100*(counter_none/len(N5)))) + '%')
```

It works on small scale, however, it takes ages of run on real file.

I am new to python, and have little experience in other programming languages. So if my question looks stupid for you, I am sorry. Also, I am not a native speaker, so apologies for my poor English.

Comment: I'm not sure of what the code do by itself (and you forgot to indent at the beginning, you I assume you code is right in your text editor). I think, being the file that huge, that by storing the results in a list, you RAM go full and the SO begins to store in virtual memory, on the hard disk, which is way slower!. Check for your ram, and if it's not the problem, make a comment or update your question. Also, don't be sorry for your english: there are plenty of native speakers that write "I have more then you".

Comment: @LeonardoHerbas Yes it's ident on my text editor. The code is splitting each item come from the list N5 (I read the file in and store it as N5). For example, the code will spilt a N5 list item 'a5b5 c5 d5 e5\tf5' into 'a5b5' 'c5' 'd5' 'e5' 'f5' and doing the same for N4, then compare them.

And yes, it's using a lot of virtual memory: almost 11 GB : (

Comment: remove all these unnecessary `str`-calls.

Comment: Updated the code, which can be ran with terminal. It might gives you a better understanding what these code are doing.

Comment: I don't understand the code and the example!
It seems in this example code, all 3 lines fall in 3rd condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert some of the lists into generators, which reduces the memory consumption considerably. Only the N4 list must be in memory, because it is traversed many times:

```
def iter_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as inp:
        for line in inp:
            line = line.split(' ')
            yield line[:-1] + line[-1].split('\t')

def do_correction(n4, n5):
    n4 = list(n4)

    for words_n5 in n5:
        for words_n4 in n4:

            # if n4 y == n5
            if (words_n4[0]+words_n4[1] == words_n5[0] and
                words_n4[2] == words_n5[1] and
                words_n4[3] == words_n5[2] and
                words_n4[4] >= words_n5[3]):
                yield words_n4[:-1] + words_n5[3:]
                break

            # if x n4 == n5
            elif (words_n4[0] in words_n5[0] and
                words_n4[1] == words_n5[1] and
                words_n4[2] == words_n5[2] and
                words_n4[3] == words_n5[3] and
                words_n4[4] >= words_n5[4]):
                idx = words_n5[0].find(words_n4[0])
                yield [words_n5[:idx], words_n5[idx:]], words_n5[1:]
                break
        else: # not found
            yield ['none'] + words_n5

with open('corrected', 'w') as output:
    for words in do_correction(iter_file('N4'), iter_file('N5')):
        output.write('%s\t%s' %(' '.join(words[:-1]), words[-1]))
```

Next, you can convert parts of N4 into a dictionary, which makes lookups much faster:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def iter_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as inp:
        for line in inp:
            line = line.split(' ')
            yield line[:-1] + line[-1].split('\t')

def do_correction(n4, n5):
    n4_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for words_n4 in n4:
        n4[words_n4[2], words_n4[3]].append(words_n4)

    for words_n5 in n5:
        words_n4 = next(
            (words_n4 for words_n4 in n4_dict[words_n5[1], words_n5[2]]
                if (words_n4[0]+words_n4[1] == words_n5[0] and
                words_n4[4] >= words_n5[3])),
            None)
        if words_n4:
            yield words_n4[:-1] + words_n5[3:]
        else:
            words_n4 = next(
                (words_n4 for words_n4 in n4_dict[words_n5[2], words_n5[3]]
                    if (words_n4[0] in words_n5[0] and
                    words_n4[1] == words_n5[1] and
                    words_n4[4] >= words_n5[4])),
                None)
            if words_n4:
                idx = words_n5[0].find(words_n4[0])
                yield [words_n5[:idx], words_n5[idx:]], words_n5[1:]
            else: # not found
                yield ['none'] + words_n5

with open('corrected', 'w') as output:
    for words in do_correction(iter_file('N4'), iter_file('N5')):
        output.write('%s\t%s' %(' '.join(words[:-1]), words[-1]))
```

Comment: Wow, a lot of thanks! Thought it's way beyond my Python knowledge right now(I am a newbie), but for sure I will look more into it, thanks again!